# ¿Cómo ir a una parte espécifica de un Layout?

Tags: android, layout

Tengo una app en la que selecciono un texto y lo guardo en un CardView, y cuando le de a ese card view, teniene que llevarme a la parte del texto que he subrayado.
Pero no sé como hacer que al pulsar el CardView con el texto subrayado me lleve y me alinee esa parte espécifica en lo alto de el layout que lo visualice.

Comment: Es importante agregues tu código y layouts de otra forma esta pregunta es amplia y solo basada en opiniones.

Comment: Perdón Jorge por no añadir el código, era solo un planteamiento porque aún tengo que desarrollar el código con los CardViews, conforme lo haga lo editaré. Gracias

Comment: Escribes: "cuando le de a ese card view". ¿Le des qué, click? Aclara también cómo tienes desarrollada la sección del card view y el alineado. Es decir, está el card view dentro de un scroll view o un recycler view? ¿Lo que quieres es que el layout haga scroll de manera que el texto seleccionado esté visible?